# Get the id of selected checkboxes in gridview (Asp.net) c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two columns one for id & other for checkboxes.
i have taken checkboxes inside the gridview.
i wanted to see the checked values inside the gridview , If checkboxes are checked then i want those values i.e id
Asp.net

Comment: i didnt get answer yet i tried this earlier also but i am getting all values from database as i wanted only checked values. Suppose i checked only 3 values then i want only that 3 values not all the values

Comment: you just take value of checked checkboes and create the string of id, i think will work for you

Comment: i write the code for that but not getting values. here when i slect that checkboxes then also it gives false values. please help me

Comment: I am using following code, tell me its right or not : foreach (GridViewRow row in reviewgrid.Rows) { { CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkmark"); if (cb.Checked) { string markid = reviewgrid.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); Response.Write(markid); }

Comment: i got the problem i didnt called ispostback method in pageload. now its working. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach(Gridviewrow gvr in Gridview1.Rows)
{
 if(((CheckBox)gvr.findcontrol("CheckBox1")).Checked == true)
 {

   int uPrimaryid= gvr.cells["uPrimaryID"];
 }
}
```

Comment: I think his problem is that with a normal asp:CheckBoxField you can't actually set it's ID, so you have to convert it to a template field?

Comment: i used the code but its not giving checked values ie id :foreach (GridViewRow row in reviewgrid.Rows)     {      CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkmark");              if (cb.Checked == true)         {             int markid = Convert.ToInt32(reviewgrid.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);          }     }

Answer (score 1):

What you will have to do is use a template field:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Field">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div style="display: block">
                                    <asp:Checkbox Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Field") %>'
                                        runat="server" ID="chkField"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then you can do:

```
foreach (DataGridRow dr in DataGrid1.Rows)
{
    ((CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("chkField")).Checked
}
```

to see if it's checked

Answer (score 1):

in your aspx you have the following

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridViewID" runat="server" DataKeyNames="DataKey1,DataKey2,DataKey3" >
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="selected">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:CheckBox ID="checkBoxID" runat="server" 
                 Checked='<%# Bind("Selected") %>'
                 OnCheckedChanged="checkBoxID_CheckedChanged" 
                 AccessKey='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'  
                 AutoPostBack="True" />
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then in your event handler you do something similar to this:

```
protected void checkBoxID_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
    var rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(checkbox.AccessKey);
    var gridView = GetErhebungModulGridView();
    var dataKey = gridView.DataKeys[rowIndex];
    if (dataKey != null)
    {
        var dataKey1 = dataKey["DataKey1"];
        var dataKey2 = dataKey["DataKey2"];
        var dataKey3 = dataKey["DataKey3"];

        //Do something with the variables keys above

    }
}
```

Comment: what's GetErhebungModulGridView()?

Comment: GetErhebungModulGridView() is simply a FindControl("id") call that we've encapsulated in a method because it is used in multiple locations - sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:gridview id="gv" runat="server">
    <columns>
    <asP:TemplateField>
       <Asp:checkbox id="chk" runat="server" />
       <Asp:literal id="ltlID" runat="server" visible="false" text='<%#eval("ID")%>' />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </columns>
</asp:gridview>

For each row as gridviewrow in gv.rows
    if ctype(row.findcontrol("chk"),checkbox).checked then
       Dim _ID as integer = ctype(row.findcontrol("ltlID"),literal).text
    end if
next
```